# Уникальное поле по двум столбцам

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть таблица book_authors которая связывает две таблицы, `books` и `authors` связь многие-ко-многим. В таблицы `book_authors` есть поля `book_id` и `author_id`. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы эти поля были уникальными, т.е. чтобы не было дубликатов записей, например не должно быть:

```
id  book_id  author_id
1      1          2
2      1          2
         ...
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Comment: `alter table book_authors 
    add constraint constraint_name
        unique (book_id, author_id);`

Answer (score 5):

Как уже упомянул коллега @ЮрийСПб в комментариях, вы можете сделать:

```sql
ALTER TABLE book_authors
  ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (book_id, author_id);
```

Но в таком случае в вашей таблице совершенно
не нужен синтетический первичный ключ `id`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE book_authors (
  author_id INTEGER REFERENCES authors(id)
, book_id   INTEGER REFERENCES   books(id)
, PRIMARY KEY (author_id, book_id)
)
;
```